# How to make nested child forms in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, mdi

In my windows form application I am using 10 forms.It is fine when only a parent and single child form are used at a time. But in case of multiple use of child form I am getting problem and not able to use them as child forms.They are not working as child form.
                                 Your any effort would be helpful for me.

Thanking You In Advance

Comment: What do you mean under "working as child form"?

Comment: Are you in the environment of a mdi container?

Comment: in parent child formation i need to open 4 child form continuously .

Comment: yes ANDREW in my case it seems i need a sub parent form type property

Comment: What role is JavaScript playing here ?

Answer (score 2):

A child form's MdiParent property need only be set to your MDI container form. Make sure the MDI form's IsMdiContainer = true.

```
foreach (Form myForm in ChildForms)
    myForm.MdiParent = myMdiContainer;   // alternatively use 'this'
```